# How does $\pi$ become $\pi^2$?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I am currently doing integration and cannot seem to understand this question

> $x\cos\left({\pi}x\right)$

I have tried following the following

> Formula I have used:$∫f g′= f g − ∫ f′g$
>   
>  f = $x$ 
> f'= $1$ 
> g = 
>   $\dfrac{\sin\left({\pi}x\right)}{{\pi}}$
>   
> g'= $cos({\pi}x)$

The end result should be the following:

> $\dfrac{{\pi}x\sin\left({\pi}x\right)+\cos\left({\pi}x\right)}{{\pi}^2}$

I cannot seem to understand how that ends up being the end result.

Comment: Which part exactly do you not understand?

Comment: Did you integrate $f'g$? If you did, you get $\pi^2$ in the denominator. The rest is just finding a common denominator.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int udv = uv - \int vdu$$

$$u = x$$
$$du = dx$$
$$dv = \cos(\pi x)$$
$$v = \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi}$$

$$ =\frac{x\sin(\pi x)}{\pi} - \int \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi}dx $$
$$ =\frac{x\sin(\pi x)}{\pi} +  \frac{\cos(\pi x)}{\pi^2} + C$$
$$ = \frac{\pi x \sin(\pi x) + \cos(\pi x)}{\pi^2} +C $$

Answer (score 1):

As you said:
$$\int x \cos(x) dx = x\frac{sin(\pi x)}{\pi} - \int \frac{sin(\pi x)}{\pi}$$

So $\pi^2$ origin from the last integral.
Infact:
$$\int \frac{sin(\pi x)}{\pi} = - \frac{cos^2(\pi x)}{\pi^2}$$